# Chrome-Extension eventHandler in React

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I'm currently trying to build a Chrome extension. To do this I'm using a react app. All the rendering and stuff is working. The problems are the chrome event handlers.

In my react app I have a context.

Inside this context is a `useEffect` hook where I register the events:

```
useEffect(() => {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(myListener)
}, []);
```

The listener function uses variables from `useState` within the context so I have to update the listener every time these variables change.

Of course there is the `removeEventListener` function, but when I call it, it does nothing because the function has already changed, and because of this Chrome thinks there is no such listener registered.

Does anyone know how to remove the old listeners or just clear all listeners?

Comment: Simply store the old function reference in a separate variable.

Comment: Thank you. Could you send me a code snippet of that?

Comment: I think I managed to do what you meant. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution code snippet:

```
const handlerRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    if(handlerRef.current){
        chrome.yourField.yourUpdate.removeListener(handlerRef.current);
    }
    chrome.yourField.yourUpdate.addListener(handler);
}, [yourDependencies]);
useEffect(() => {
     handlerRef.current = handler;
});
```

Thanks to @wOxxOm!